# MSE of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to know how to calculate the MSE for a Uniform Distribution on $(θ,2θ)$

I know that MSE is the variance of the Method of Moments Estimator (MME). I have found this to be $3θ/2$.

Then I think I should calculate the $Var(2/3X\bar)$. Assuming that the bias of the MME is $0$. I think the answer is $3(θ^2) / 48n$. However I am unsure if this is the correct computation.

Comment: Hi Flo -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. $\theta$ is a parameter of the distribution. An estimator is a function of the data that estimates a parameter, not a function of the parameters. The method-of-moments estimator is the solution of the equation $\bar X=\frac32\hat\theta$, which is $\hat\theta=\frac23\bar X$. Also, the MSE is usually the MSE of an estimator; it's not clear to me what you mean by the MSE for a distribution. Perhaps you mean the MSE of the method-of-moments estimator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the mean squared error (MSE) does not apply to a distribution, but to an **estimator**.  Usually, we are interested in the estimator of a parameter of a distribution, but not always:  I could, for example, ask for the MSE of the maximum likelihood estimator of the variance of a parametric distribution.

Thus, your question is improperly posed.  The "MSE of a distribution" makes no sense.  You have to specify the estimator of interest, and it cannot be assumed that this estimator is a method of moments (MoM) estimator; moreover, it cannot be assumed that the estimator estimates a parameter.

If I make the assumption that you are interested in the MSE of the MoM estimator of the parameter $\theta$ from a continuous uniform distribution on $(\theta,2\theta)$, then we first have to determine what the MoM estimator is:  for a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of IID observations from $$X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(\theta,2\theta),$$ the sample mean is set equal to the expectation of $X$; i.e., $$\bar x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{3\theta}{2}.$$  The formal calculation of $\operatorname{E}[X]$ is simple; we write $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{x=\theta}^{2\theta} x \frac{1}{2\theta - \theta} \, dx = \left[\frac{x^2}{2\theta} \right]_{x=\theta}^{2\theta} = \frac{4\theta^2 - \theta^2}{2\theta} = \frac{3\theta}{2}.$$  Consequently, the MoM estimator of $\theta$ is $$\tilde \theta = \frac{2}{3}\bar x.$$  The MSE is given by $$\operatorname{MSE}[\tilde \theta] = \operatorname{Var}[\tilde\theta] + \operatorname{E}[\tilde\theta - \theta]^2;$$ that is, it is the sum of the variance and squared bias.  We have $$\operatorname{E}[\tilde \theta] = \frac{2}{3}\operatorname{E}[\bar x] = \frac{2}{3n} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[x_i] = \frac{2}{3n} \cdot n \frac{3\theta}{2} = \theta,$$ so the MoM estimator is unbiased, and the MSE equals the variance of $\tilde\theta$:  $$\operatorname{Var}[\tilde\theta] = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \operatorname{Var}[\bar x].$$  Since the observations are independent, the variance of their sum is equal to the sum of their variances; i.e., $$\operatorname{Var}[\bar x] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[x_i] = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}[X] = \frac{\theta^2}{12n}.$$  The calculation of this variance is simple:  $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \int_{x=\theta}^{2\theta} \frac{x^2}{\theta} \, dx - \left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right)^2 = \left[\frac{x^3}{3\theta}\right]_{x=\theta}^{2\theta} - \frac{9\theta^2}{4} = \frac{\theta^2}{12},$$ as claimed.  We therefore conclude $$\operatorname{MSE}[\tilde\theta] = \frac{4}{9} \operatorname{Var}[\bar x] = \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{\theta^2}{12n} = \frac{\theta^2}{27n}.$$

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: you realise this is from 4 years ago?

Comment: Nice answer. However, I was thinking (while reading the question) that the OP may have been after the minimum mean square error estimator. Unfortunately the question is so confused it's hard to be quite sure what the OP wanted.